# show .jps 3d image file thumbnails in folders on windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, images, windows-explorer, thumbnails, 3d

A .jps file is a 3d image file which in reality is a jpg with leftright images joined ([JPEG Stereoscopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_Stereo#JPEG_Stereoscopic))

Months ago i found a registry hack for windows that enabled explorer to show the thumbnails of these .jps files...but i lost that change after formating the pc and now i cant find the web where it expecified the registry keys to change...

Maybe someone knows how this could be done again? Or which registry keys could have been? Or other ways to do it.

Comment: It's not a registry hack, but..? http://www.mtbs3d.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14969

Comment: @skub The web shows that the comment and the response are both from 10 hours ago but if it really was your comment dupped as a response put your own response and i will vote it over the other one...

Answer (score 2):

Try this utility:

http://www.mtbs3d.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14969

It parses JPS, MPS and PNS files and generates thumbnails so explorer can show them.
Only for Windows Vista/7 (not compatible with XP)

Comment: Good find, Filipe!

Comment: Thanks, althought i installed that too and it didnt generate any thumbnails (cleared thumbnail cache and rebooted too after installing...with no results), it was a .dll in its program files folder so i dont know if i had to do something more after installing it...

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded those reg files a year ago to show thumbnails for mpo and jps images on Windows 7. I think this is what you're looking for..

JPS-> http://dl.free.fr/getfile.pl?file=/IZAvzztS

MPO-> http://dl.free.fr/getfile.pl?file=/2QFX1Blh